# Using Web application on Mobile in Offline Mode

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, jsonp, offline

I have some problem here. I am developing a web application for mobile apps. I used JSONP to get data from a web server, and it works perfectly fine.

My question is, what If I'm in offline MOde?

My Idea is to download the JSONP file from the web server and save to my local or to my phone.

Is this a good Idea? If it is, how do I do it?

If not, what are my other options.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [HTML5 cache manifest API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/):

```
CACHE MANIFEST
myfile.jsonp
```